# SqlDataSource adds new columns to Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, sqldatasource

```
<div style="width:100%; height:200px; overflow:scroll; border-color:White;">
        <asp:GridView ID="UsersGridView" runat="server" 
            CssClass="label" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%" 
            AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataSourceID="UsersDataSource" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fleet Description" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HtmlEncode="True" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fleet Code" HeaderText="Fleet Code" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="Last Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="User Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" 
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UsersDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT        UserDataAssociation.Fleet as &quot;Fleet Code&quot;, UserDataAssociation.FirstName as &quot;First Name&quot;, UserDataAssociation.LastName as &quot;Last Name&quot;, aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Membership.Email, 
                     UserDataAssociation.Phone
FROM            aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN
                     aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN
                     UserDataAssociation ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = UserDataAssociation.UserId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

I have this gridview for the sqldatasource with a select statement. However when the page is loaded, the gridview has double its original columns, created by the datasource. I would like that not to be the case obviously.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Gridview` `AutoGenerateColumns` property to False

Answer (score 3):

There is an option to "Auto generate fields" in the edit columns menu, uncheck it. When you selected the SqlDataSource as your datasource, it created the columns, and for some reason it did not uncheck the auto generate fields option, which is why  it's creating it twice. When you click on the grid view, there will be a little white arrow in the upper right hand corner that gives more options, if you expand that menu, click on "Edit Columns", and then you can uncheck the "auto generate fields" option. Or simply set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to *false*.

[image]